# None of the system sound effects work in Linux Mint. Other audio plays fine

Tags: linux, audio, linux-mint, bluetooth

I'm currently using Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa and when I installed it in the first place months ago the sound and everything worked fine. It still does in fact, the problem is that none of the system sound effects work such as boot sound, window close/open etc. I'm able to play music properly and hear sound from videos as well.

I'm willing to provide more details as long as I can get this issue resolved. I also have the issue with my Bluetooth where the audio sink doesn't work with my Portronics wireless speaker or any audio device - I get the error stating "stream setup failed", I searched and tried a lot of things online but never got to resolve these two issues.

These issues started when I was messing around with Linux Mint after installing it, I quite frankly don't remember what I did to create these issues either.

Comment: So I am confused... sounds play fine, except Cinnamon system sounds? BTW, these two problems are probably not related, they should be two distinct questions.

Answer (score 1):

System sound depend on libcanberra, try install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-pulse
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Sound applet inside System Settings (or click the Volume applet and select Sound Settings), then click the Sound Effects tab, turn up the Alert Volume (I always set mine to Max) and verify it is turned on, and the volume is on at the bottom of page.

I often have to exit this applet and reopen it for effects to "take", or turn them off and back on again but I am not sure if this is me or a "bug". Then click the play arrow next to the various sound effects, they should playback normally.

I cannot answer the Bluetooth issue, that should be a separate question.

Comment: Everything is enabled and set high which is what's weird.. https://imgur.com/Pl78vki when I click on those play buttons near those sounds effects, im able to hear those sound effects.

Comment: Yes it is a little weird... Mine should be basically "stock"  https://imgur.com/8dSnvVP

Comment: do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @Lucas Not really, if the sounds play there but not, for example, when you log-off and on, I don't know what would be causing that... There isn't really anywhere else this is addressed/changed to my knowledge, and sounds are not part of theme packages. Sorry.